# Faster Algorithm for counting non-negative triple $(a, b, c)$ satisfied $(a + b + c \le S)$ and $(a \times b \times c \le T)$

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms

Now this will be dicussed on (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4230187/faster-algorithm-for-counting-non-negative-tripplea-b-c-satisfied-a-b-c) only.

Comment: This question is more suitable for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also posted to m.se, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4230187/faster-algorithm-for-counting-non-negative-tripplea-b-c-satisfied-a-b-c without notice to either site.

Comment: I thought 2 sites are about different subjects :( sorry about that

Comment: @VoHoangAnh: Performing a trivial edit (such as adding a single, needless space) only in order to trigger the reopening process is not right. Anyway, I have voted to reopen your question: it is obvious that you have spent quite some time investigating it, so it deserves a second chance. Keep in mind, though, that you are asking several questions in a single post, which goes against the rules of this place: if two people answer two different of your questions, which answer should be accepted? This motivates the rule: one single question per post.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about the rule, I will take serious about the rule and will not violate in the future. Should I delete this blog ?

Comment: Whether the two sites are about different sites or not, it is bad manners to post to both without the transparency of informing each of what you are doing. You may cause much duplicated effort that way. It's also inefficient from your point of view, since an answer or comment on one site might be just what some user on the other site needs to come up with a complete answer. So, please, don't do it. Post to one site, wait, and if, say, a week goes by without a full answer, consider posting to the other site, and linking each post to the other.

Comment: @VoHoangAnh: No, there is no reason to delete it, don't worry.